# Can the "New Activity" dot be changed to not require an entire line of space

Tags: feature-request, design

[image]

I changed the containing H3 to contain the following CSS. I think this provides a better view.

```css
.summary h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've seen those dots before in the listing, and they already appear as you suggest: on the same line as the title. I think something is going wrong in your browser.

Comment: @NicolBolas This may be a bug as if I change the link's html to not have the class `.question-hyperlink` then it displays in a similar way to the second picture.

Comment: Do you have any userscripts or browser add-ons that may be getting involved?

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah yes, it's one of three userscripts. I can't see any more active questions so I'll have to further narrow it down tomorrow and submit an issue to the creator of the script.